# how calculate a conditional mutate in R with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

i have this problem.
I want calculate a new variable, this variable it conditioned to other variables:

P46A is a variable of level of education and P47 is the years in this level.

The idea is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR7Lf.jpg)

And i use the dplyr:

```
Datos %>% mutate(newvariable= if_else(P46A %in% c(-98,-99),NA,
if_else(P46A %in% c(0,1), P47, if_else(P46A %in% c(2:4),P47+3,
if_else(P46A %in% c(5:7,11),P47+16, if_else(P46A %in% c(8,9),P47+23,P47+26))))))
```

In other words, i want calculate a newvariable dependent of the values in other varaible. When i run the code R print error.

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be type logical, not double.
```

thanks!

Comment: In the image is: If P46A ==10 -> P47+26

Comment: `if_else` is restrictive on type. Try using `NA_integer_` instead of `NA`

Comment: Thaks my friend

Comment: You are always welcome! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also trying replacing the if_else statements with a case_when statement.  It makes for much more legible code.

```
Datos %>% mutate(
  newvariable= case_when(
    P46A %in% c(-98, -99) ~ NA_real_,
    P46A %in% c(0, 1) ~ P47,
    P46A %in% c(5:7, 11) ~ P47 + 16,
    P46A %in% 8:9 ~ P47 + 23,
    TRUE ~ P47 + 26
  )
)
```